# 'Awesome Print' on the same line

Tags: ruby, awesomeprint

Is it possible using awesome_print to print on the same line?

For example, consider the following loop:

```
(0..5).each do |i|
  ap i
end
```

Each instance of *i* appears on a new line, but I would like to have the result as *012345*, on the same line.

Failing this, what other ruby print methods could achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
(0..5).each do |i|
  print i #prints on the same line
end
print "\n" #when you're done, insert a line break for neatness
```

Comment: Also it looks like you can pass in options.
https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print
Passing in {multiline: false} may or may not help